# Существует ли проверка интерфейса шаблона C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

В книге Бьярне Страуструпа "Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием C++, 2-е издание.", глава 19, пункт 19.3.3 написано, что в С++14 мы можем использовать и применять к аргументам шаблона некую концепцию или требования шаблона.

```
template<typename T>  // Для всех типов T
    requires Element<T>() // таких, что является Element 
 class vector {
 // . . .
 };
```

Вот пара концепций, которые предоставлены в книге (там их много):

```
Element<E> (): Е может быть элементом контейнера
Number<N> () : N ведет себя как число, поддерживая операции +, -, * и /.
```

Но этот код не компилируется. Пожалуйста, объясните есть ли ключевое слово ***requires*** и вообще концепции шаблонов в С++?

Comment: Пока нет. В будущем будет. Сейчас всё реализуется через `is_detected` и SFINAE

Comment: У меня нет этой книги, но я предполагаю, что автор надеется, что сможем в C++14, а не утверждает об этом.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это было исключено из стандарта.

Answer (score 12):

Концепций нет в С++14, и их не будет в С++17.

В настоящее время концепции реализованы только в GCC 6.1+, и включаются ключом командной строки `-fconcepts`:

```
> type main.cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
requires sizeof(T) < 4
void f() {
    std::cout << "< 4\n";
}

template<typename T>
requires sizeof(T) >= 4
void f() {
    std::cout << ">= 4\n";
}    

int main() {
    f<short>();
    f<double>();
}

> g++ -fconcepts -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp && a
< 4
>= 4
```

Краткое описание синтаксиса можно прочитать на [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

Comment: А оно уже точно "концепция" на русском, или всё же "концепт"?